# Problems with index

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I try to create 10 subplots for 10 different regions on earth. At the end there should be a pdf with 10 pages each containing 10 subplots for one region.
But I get the Error Message:

```
subplots[l,i].scatter(rad_cool_avg[l,:],prec_avg[l,:])
IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5
```

Here my code:

```
for i in range(0,10): # loop for all plots (stations)

 for l in range(0,10): # loop for all plot (grid sizes)

  if(i==0.):
    rad_cool_latavg[l,:,:]=np.mean(rad_cool_double[:,ls-ls+ar+2,:],axis=1)
    rad_cool_avg[l,:]=np.mean(rad_cool_latavg[l,:,j_lon[l]-ar:j_lon[l]+ar+2],axis=1)
    prec_latavg[l,:,:]=np.mean(prec_double[:,ls-ar:ls+ar+2,:],axis=1)
    prec_avg[l,:]=np.mean(prec_latavg[l,:,j_lon[l]-ar:j_lon[l]+ar+2],axis=1)
  else:
    rad_cool_latavg[l,:,:]=np.mean(rad_cool_double[:,ls-ar:ls+ar,:],axis=1)
    rad_cool_avg[l,:]=np.mean(rad_cool_latavg[l,:,j_lon[l]-ar:j_lon[l]+ar],axis=1)
    prec_latavg[l,:,:]=np.mean(prec_double[:,ls-ar:ls+ar,:],axis=1)
    prec_avg[l,:]=np.mean(prec_latavg[l,:,j_lon[l]-ar:j_lon[l]+ar],axis=1)

   #print(l)

 subplots[l,i].scatter(rad_cool_avg[l,:],prec_avg[l,:])
 pfile.savefig()
```

I still do not understand the Errormessage because, if i print l there are all 10 index for 10 points. Can someone tell me what's the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Either `l` or `i` is 5 at this point in the loop, and one of the index objects has on 5 elements in that dimensions.  Remember, Python list and numpy array indexing runs from 0 to `n-1` for size `n` objects.  So you have to figure out when array isn't size 10.

Comment: yes, but i printed both and the size is 10 for both of it.

Comment: Did you check the size of the subplots? Are there 100 of them (10,10)?

Comment: Where do you define `subplots`? Without knowing how you define your subplot grid, it's just random guessing here. See [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I am just a beginner in using python.. I am not sure if it is the definition of the subplot but I used `fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.2,top=0.95, right=0.95)`